# Setting up CertManager on GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, cert-manager

I'm trying to setup CertManager on k8s and I keep getting the following error:

```
Error syncing to GCP: error running load balancer syncing routine: error initializing translator env: secrets "letsencrypt-cluster-issuer-key" not found
```

It looks like the name of the generated certificate has a suffix to it, thus it can't find it.

My configuration

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: kong-ingress
  namespace: api
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-cluster-issuer
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: "api"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: MY_DOMAIN
    http:
      paths:
      - path: "/*"
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: kong
            port:
              number: 8000
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - MY_DOMAIN
      secretName: letsencrypt-cluster-issuer-key
---
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-cluster-issuer
spec:
  acme:
    server: https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    email: MY_EMAIL
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-cluster-issuer-key
    solvers:
      - http01:
          ingress:
            class: gce
---
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: api-certificate
  namespace: api
spec:
  secretName: letsencrypt-cluster-issuer-key
  duration: 2160h # 90d
  renewBefore: 360h # 15d
  subject:
    organizations:
      - MY_ORGANIZATION
  isCA: false
  privateKey:
    algorithm: RSA
    encoding: PKCS1
    size: 2048
  usages:
    - server auth
    - client auth
  # At least one of a DNS Name, URI, or IP address is required.
  dnsNames:
    - MY_DOMAIN
  # Issuer references are always required.
  issuerRef:
    name: letsencrypt-cluster-issuer
    kind: ClusterIssuer
```

Outputs:

```
❯ kubectl -n api get certificates
NAME                             READY   SECRET                           AGE
api-certificate                  False   letsencrypt-cluster-issuer-key   6m14s
letsencrypt-cluster-issuer-key   False   letsencrypt-cluster-issuer-key   6m9s

❯ kubectl -n api get secrets
NAME                                   TYPE                                  DATA   AGE
api-certificate-vn2dj                  Opaque                                1      7m8s
default-token-5vd7p                    kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3      8m35s
letsencrypt-cluster-issuer-key-76cvz   Opaque                                1      7m4s
```

As you can see, the generated secret has this suffix on it and causes the problem I think. I've also tried to move the certificate around to following namespaces `default`, `kube-system`, `cert-manager` without any success

Versions:

- CertManager 1.8.0
- GKE 1.23.5-gke.2400

Any ideas?

Comment: SUGGESTIONS: 1) See if this link helps (look at the rest of the thread, too): https://stackoverflow.com/a/65252900/421195. 2) If you get it working, consider adding your solution as a "response" to this question, then "accept" it.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't help - I want to leverage Google's LB, not ignore them by using NGINX.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Whatever the problem is, it has something to do with the namespaces. Once I've moved everything to the default namespace it started to work.

Any clues on how to set it up with a namespace?